# Is it actually possible to connect to ActiveMQ via XMPP and query/browse queues using "AciveMQ.Agent chatroom" feature?

Tags: xmpp, activemq-classic

I tried what I think are 4 most popular XMPP (aka "Jabber")
clients (Spark, Pidgin, Psi, Pandion) to connect to ActiveMQ instance (Apache ActiveMQ ver. 5.3.0)
on XMMP connector with an idea to use the "AciveMQ.Agent chatroom" for querying queues/etc
and no success at all

Some of them fail with 'Unknown error', some don't fail but kind of "hang"...

interestingly, some communication does indeed reach the ActiveMQ side, because when I close a client it spits an exception "could not close" or something to that effect...
and if I try "register new user" option (present on most clients" the ActiveMQ also spits some most cryptic warning message

But I was never able to get to the point when I could see or specify "ActiveMQ.Agent" as chatroom and issue any commands...

Before I waste any more time on this curious feature, I would like to hear whether anyone had any success with it?

Thank you!

PS: BTW, the book "ActiveMQ in Action book" 
http://www.manning.com/snyder/ 
shows that it is apparently works and is very easy using some Mac client (AdiumX), but I wanted it on a Windows PC ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is for 2.0.0 linux version:
http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloadServlet?filename=spark/spark_2_0_0.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Spark 2.0.0?

As far as I remember there was some bug in 2.5.x versions.

There's a "Jabber clients compatibility" section here:

http://activemq.apache.org/xmpp.html#XMPP-Jabberclientscompatibility

It'd be great to document more of them (specify problems and workarounds).

I'll try to find some time these days to test on windows. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Topics work perfectly for me following http://activemq.apache.org/xmpp.html with ActiveMQ 5.5 and Spark 2.0. But so far I can't figure out how to connect to queues - maybe not possible.